# Is there a way to style sibling elements when a class is applied to one of them?

Tags: css, reactjs, sass, carousel

I'm using 'react-multi-carousel'. This carousel has dots for the number of slides. Each dot is actually an `li` element with a data attribute called `[data-index='X']`, X being the slide number. For example, in my project the final slide is 7, so the final `li` element has `[data-index='7']` and the class added to it is `.react-multi-carousel-dot--active`.

My question is: Is there a way I can change the visibility to hidden to all sibling `li` elements when this last element has this class?

All I have so far is

```
[data-index='7'].react-multi-carousel-dot--active {
      visibility: hidden;
    }
```

But of course this only modifies that last `li` element.
Is there a css or a scss solution to this problem?

Answer (score 0):

css is like a waterfall, you can't select up only down.

for a css solution, if you have control over the carousel dots, render them in reverse order. then to display them do something like flex-direction: row-reverse; and then you could do

`li[data-index='7'].react-multi-carousel-dot--active ~ li { visibility: hidden; }`

`~` is a sibling selector, but will only work on siblings after itself.

you probably can't do this tho because you don't have control over how the carousel dots are rendered, not sure.

this has the same concept https://codepen.io/theskillwithin/pen/GEmroE